# How to use pageXOffset?

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to Javascript, so I know this is really basic question to you, but to me, it is difficult.
Please help me with any advise.

I'd like to change my image size when the screen size is smaller than 960px to make Responsive website using Javascript.
The real size of image is 363 x 88 and I want to switch to 275 x 55.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: you can also achieve this in css using @media query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a media query in your css like this: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/g8hbwz19/1/

in your head section add this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

In you css add something like this:

```
.img {
  width: 363px;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  .img {
    width: 275px;
  }
}
```